# Eliminate rows with identical ID but different condition code (1 or 2)

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a large data set with over a thousand participant.  Each participant has a unique ID.  Each time a participant was tested their data was entered on a separate row.  Participants were tested under two conditions coded "1" and "2".  Some participants were always tested under condition 1 Some were always tested under condition 2.  Still other participants were tested under both condition 1 and 2.

For this analysis, I want to eliminate participants that were tested under two different conditions, retaining only participants that were always tested under the same condition.

I have to find rows with identical id's (showing same participant) but different condition codes and eliminate those rows.  I am familiar with subset, but I am not sure how to create the data subset I need in this case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(old_data)

new_data <- old_data[ , if (uniqueN(condition_code) == 1) .SD, by = participant_id]
```

`setDT` adds the `data.table` class to your `data.frame` so it can be passed to `data.table` methods. `uniqueN` is equivalent to (but faster than) `length(unique())` and this statement ensures there is exactly one unique condition code associated with a given participant (as identified by their `participant_id`).

`.SD` is a temporary data set created within each group. Without further modification, `.SD` simply represents the full set of columns and rows associated with a particular `participant_id`, so the construction says to return all data associated with `participant_id`s passing your condition; for those that don't pass, return nothing (`NULL` is technically returned, and then those rows are dropped in clean-up)

Comment: Did you meant `if(uniqueN(condition_code) == 1) .SD`

Comment: @akrun indeed, sorry was being sloppy without sample data to test